# Cross Domain Goal Funnels and unique data?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, conversions, goal-tracking

I've been tasked with setting up cross domain tracking and goal funnels.

I maintain several ecommerce sites and we want to set up goal funnels to track where we are most successful. However, these funnel steps are across different domain names. This is why I set up cross domain tracking, I got the goal funnels working, except each view I created to separate the funnels under the cross domain UA property show identical visitor data of all the domains included.

We want to see the domain specific visitor data for each domain name, in addition to the goal funnel conversion stats.

So my question is: Would it be better to create a new UA property and add additional tracking codes to each different domain? Or create a new view under the cross-domain UA property and filter only traffic of each domain name, this would mean having 2 views for each domain (one for cross-domain goal funnels, and one for domain specific visitor data).